# Generic ValidationAttribute with dynamic Entity.Property unique check (set at run time)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I currently have a custom ValidationAttribute that ensures that a property is unique.  It looks like this:

```
public class UniqueLoginAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            Context db = new Context();
            if (db.Users.SingleOrDefault(user => user.Login == (string)value) != null)
            {
               return new ValidationResult(validationContext.DisplayName + " is already taken.");
            }
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

What I'd like to is make this Validation work with any Entity/Property combination.  In other words, set both the Entity (in this case "Users") and Property (in this case "Login"), at runtime.  I've found some examples of DynamicLINQ, but I'd like a pure EF solution, which I can't seem to find.

Comment: How will you specify the Entity type and Property name at runtime? Attributes are declarative in nature so any arguments are specified at compile time.

Comment: You can actually reflect the Entity and Property names from the validationContext... validationContext.ObjectType.Name will return the entity name and validationContext.MemberName will return the property name.

Comment: you still need to define what object and what property is to be unique. At runtime ? How ?

Comment: I share your pain. Moving from a dynamic, interpreted language like Ruby, it hard to get back into a strongly-typed / compiled language like c#. Some very simple meta programming techniques become much more complicated...

Answer (score 1):

This will work.  You need to build the expression tree manually.

Usage

```
Expression<Func<User, string>> userExp = x => x.Login;
UniqueAttribute u = new UniqueAttribute(userExp);`
```

EDIT: Removed generics to work w/ `Attribute`.  You need to use reflection w/ the runtime types to get the appropriate `SingleOrDefault` method.  Please note there is no compile time type checking on your expressions with this code.  You should always declare the expression first (the way I did in the usage sample) to avoid type problems.

```
public class UniqueAttribute 
    {
        private LambdaExpression Selector { get; set; }
        private Type EntityType { get; set; }

        public UniqueAttribute(LambdaExpression selector) {
            this.EntityType = selector.Parameters[0].Type;
            this.Selector = selector;
        }

        private LambdaExpression GeneratePredicate(object value) {
                ParameterExpression param = Selector.Parameters[0];
                Expression property = Selector.Body;
                Expression valueConst = Expression.Constant(value);
                Expression eq = Expression.Equal(property, valueConst);
                LambdaExpression predicate = Expression.Lambda(eq, new ParameterExpression[]{param});

                return predicate;
        }

        private TEntity SingleOrDefault<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> set, LambdaExpression predicate) {
            Type queryableType = typeof(Queryable);
            IEnumerable<MethodInfo> allSodAccessors = queryableType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Where(x => x.Name=="SingleOrDefault");
            MethodInfo twoArgSodAccessor = allSodAccessors.Single(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 2);
            MethodInfo withGenArgs = twoArgSodAccessor.MakeGenericMethod(new []{typeof(TEntity)});

            return (TEntity) withGenArgs.Invoke(null, new object[]{set, predicate});
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
            {

                Context db = new Context();
                if (SingleOrDefault(db.Set(EntityType), GeneratePredicate(value)) != null)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(validationContext.DisplayName + " is already taken.");
                }
                return null;
            }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't build: A generic type cannot derive from 'ValidationAttribute' because it is an attribute class

Comment: Why pass the TEntity and TProperty types?  They can be reflected from the validationContext.

Comment: @cschiewek Using generics makes the syntax easier.  Without them, you can't use the `selector` expression in the Ctor as easily.

Comment: @just.another.programmer I see, but like I said in my previous comment, it won't compile.  "A generic type cannot derive from 'ValidationAttribute' because it is an attribute class"

Comment: @cschiewek I've updated the answer to remove generics

Comment: Different error now: The type arguments for method 'UniqueAttribute.SingleOrDefault<TEntity>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TEntity>, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

This may work for you, but has the downside of needing to retrieve the full list of entities and loop through them to look for a match. You can specify the entity and property as arguments to the attribute.

```
public class UniqueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public UniqueAttribute(Type entityType, string propertyName)
    {
        _entityType = entityType;
        _propertyName = propertyName;
    }    

    private Type _entityType;
    private string _propertyName;

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        Context db = new Context();

        foreach (var item in db.Set(_entityType).ToList())
        {
           if (value.Equals(GetPropertyValue(item, _propertyName))
           {
               return new ValidationResult(validationContext.DisplayName + " is already taken.");
           }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private object GetPropertyValue(object item, string propertyName)
    {
        var type = item.GetType();
        var propInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

        return (propInfo != null) ? propInfo.GetValue(value, null) : null;
    }
}
```

}

Usage:

```
[Unique(typeof(User), "Login")]
public string Login { get; set; }
```

Comment: My DbContext does not have a GetTable method.

Comment: My bad, GetTable is the Linq version. In EF it is Set().

Comment: -1 This solution loads the *entire* DB table into memory.  That's a huge performance bottleneck.

Comment: I did say that in the answer. If there's a way of building an EF-translatable 'where' predicate using the property name as a string I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: There's lot's of ways, but in this case, it's easier to just use generics and let the compiler do the work.  All the "magic" the compiler does with lambda expressions can be reproduced manually with the methods of the `Expression` class.  See my answer for an example.